# deleting a file locally when deleting from a Firebase storage

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage, delete-file

I work on a app and I want to know if it is possible to delete a file downloaded from Firebase Storage or Google cloud, on all device using this app, when the file is deleted from from storage.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible but you have to store the uri of image fetched from internal storage. Also if you want image should be deleted in background you have to write a cloud function. It must fetch token id as well as uid of the user.

Comment: Thank you for you help, I begin with firebase functions so I have to make further search before come back.

Comment: I have found a way to delete the file on device by overriding onChildChanged in FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.

Comment: So, @tomaRv you can edit my above answer and post the correct solution. It might be helpful for others..

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing now my question was incomplet.

I use FirebaseRecyclerAdapter to display a list of data, and in data you can sometimes have the name of a audio file saved in Firebase Storage. So I have overrided onChildChanged method in adapter, and when a child is removed from database, the audio file is searched in designated folder on device, and deleted if exists. The file is also deleted in Firebase Storage through a Firebase function.

I am traveling now, when I return I will edit the question and your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To solve my problem, I have overrided onChildChanged method of FirebaseRecyclerAdapter like this :

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = MyFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Entry, EntryViewHolder> mAdapter = null;
    ...

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ...
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        // Setup adapter
        FirebaseRecyclerOptions<Entry> options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<Entry>()
                .setQuery(query, Entry.class)
                .build();

        // Setup adapter
        mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Entry, EntryViewHolder>(options) {

            @Override
            public EntryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                ...
                return view;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final EntryViewHolder viewHolder, int position, @NonNull final Entry model) {
                // Fill view holder
                ...
            }

            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull ChangeEventType type, @NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot, int newIndex, int oldIndex) {
                super.onChildChanged(type, snapshot, newIndex, oldIndex);

                // If child is removed, deleted its associated file on device if exists
                if (type.equals(ChangeEventType.REMOVED)) {
                    // Get file name from delete entry
                    final String fileName = (String) snapshot.child("fileName").getValue();
                    // Check in file exists in local, then delete it
                    File file = new File(getActivity().getFilesDir() + "/" + fileName);
                    if (file.exists()) {
                        file.delete();
                    }
                } 
            }
        };

        // Setup recycler view
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

I use a Firebase function to delete the file when an entry is deleted from realtime database. So the file is deleted on cloud and on device (if it has already been downloaded on device).